Is there any case-sensitive search engine available?
This is not a duplicate of this question about Google. I am aware that the problem of distinguishing between, say, "GaP" (gallium phosphide), "gap" (hole), and "GAP" (clothes store) is too difficult for Google Search, but I am asking whether there is any search engine at all that can distinguish these three strings of text. I know it isn't Bing, or DuckDuckGo, or Ecosia, or Mojeek... But surely there exists at least some tiny tool that recognises this problem?
